# Cloudflare API issue put request ("code":9020,"message":"Invalid DNS record type")

Tags: php, api, curl, dns, cloudflare

I am having issue while using cloudflare APIv4. Trying to update a dns record and not sure why am I receiving following error:

> {"success":false,"errors":[{"code":1004,"message":"DNS Validation Error","error_chain":[{"code":9020,"message":"Invalid DNS record type"}]}],"messages":[],"result":null}

Here is the PHP function:

```
function updateCloudflareDNS($zone_id,$dns_id, $updatedata){
 $updatedata = '[{"name":"**.****.com"},{"type":"A"},{"ttl":"1"},{"content":"8.8.8.8"},{"proxied":"true"}]';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/".$zone_id."/dns_records/".$dns_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'X-Auth-Email: **********',
    'X-Auth-Key: ***********'
));    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $updatedata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
}
```

Also, I am putting record type "A" correctly as mentioned on the [Cloudflare API documentation](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-update-dns-record)

Could someone help me out with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/api-error-9020/56258 - Take a closer look at your JSON (list of objects, rather than one object).

Comment: You've linked the API docs right in your question. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending a payload of:

> `[{"name":"**.****.com"},{"type":"A"},{"ttl":"1"},{"content":"8.8.8.8"},{"proxied":"true"}]`

Here's what the [API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-create-dns-record) expects:

> `{"type":"A", "name":"example.com", "content":"127.0.0.1", "ttl":120, "priority":10,"proxied":false}`

And this is how you properly construct JSON in PHP:

```
$POST = json_encode(array(
    "type" => "A",
    "name" => "...",
    ...
));
```

Comment: Stupid mistake.. Thanks